# Python, bot to change user_agent

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, user-agent

The code works, but not like I want it to work.

1. It does not change my browser, do not know why [image]

Only it change Remote Port. User_agent I am using from here https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/blob/master/txt/user-agents.txt

Any help I would be helpful. Could it be that my provider of internet do not allow to change  ?

Here is code:

```
import random, time, requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


USER_AGENTS_FILE = './user_agents.txt'
RUNNING = True

def LoadUserAgents(uafile=USER_AGENTS_FILE):
    uas = []
    with open(uafile, 'r') as uaf:
        for ua in uaf.readlines():
            if ua:
                uas.append(ua.strip() [0:-1-1])
    random.shuffle(uas)
    return uas

uas = LoadUserAgents()

while RUNNING == True:
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('general.usragent.override', random.choice(uas))
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
    driver.get('http://www.ipchicken.com/')
    input('Press enter to continue')
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: You have a typo in setting the Firefox config field, it should be `general.useragent.override` (useragent, not **usr**agent)...

Comment: Also, I would make a small addition to your `LoadUserAgents` method when checking for a loaded value as it currently might end up on a comment from the `user_agents.txt` file - change the `if ua:` line to `if ua and "#" not in ua:`. The whole method is inefficient but will at least give you 'valid' UserAgents...

Comment: Thank you. It works out. Funny so I missed it :) Great great thx.